# html div display attribute: handling inline-block and some boolean condition

Tags: html, frontend

I have a div tag which contains other elements like form, button etc. div is stretching to entire width of the screen. So I am told that display="inline-block" would fix the issue. But I am also using display attribute to display the div based on some condition

```
<div display={some condition}...>
```

So how to handle this situation?

Comment: there is no `display` attribute for `div` elements. Is that from some framework you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope if this helps you

**HTML**

```
<div id="selected">
  Ahmed
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
if(your condation){
  const div = document.getElementById('selected').style.display ="inline-block"
}else if(your condation){
  //code
}
.
.
.
else{
  //code
}
```